# How to find select the elements that are in one arraylist that are not in another arraylist in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I am attempting to find the difference of 2 arraylists in kotlin i.e the elements in the first arraylist that are not included in the second arraylist. The code below I believe would work for listOf but I need it to work for arraylists of strings structure instead with the same names i.e first, second and difference should all be arraylists of strings.

```
fun main() {

    private var first = ArrayList<String>()
    private var  second = ArrayList<String>()
    private var difference = ArrayList<String>()

                first.add(“a”)
                first.add(“b”)
                first.add(“c”)
                first.add(“d”)
                first.add(“e”)
                 second.add(“a”)
                 second.add(“b”)
                 second.add(“c”)
val difference = first.minus(second)

println(difference)    // [d, e]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html):

```
fun main() {
    val first = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
    println("first type: %s".format(first.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
    val second = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c")
    println("second type: %s".format(second.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
    val difference = first.minus(second)
    println(difference)
    println("difference type: %s".format(difference.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
}
```

Or instead, add the elements to the ArrayList's one by one if desired:

```
fun main() {
    val first = ArrayList<String>()
    first.add("a")
    first.add("b")
    first.add("c")
    first.add("d")
    first.add("e")
    println("first type: %s".format(first.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
    val second = ArrayList<String>()
    second.add("a")
    second.add("b")
    second.add("c")
    println("second type: %s".format(second.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
    val difference = first.minus(second)
    println(difference)
    println("difference type: %s".format(difference.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName))
}
```

**Output:**

```
first type: java.util.ArrayList
second type: java.util.ArrayList
[d, e]
difference type: java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Can I use arraylists instead of arraylistof?

Comment: I require all data structures to be arraylists instead of arraylistof.

Comment: they are the same, arrayListOf() is just a way to implement ArrayList

Comment: Note that this scales really badly (because it needs to repeatedly scan one list); you'll get much better performance if you use sets instead.